# How do I remove the drill bit from my hammer drill?

Tags: drill

I have a HD 400 Hammer drill from Black and Decker and I have no idea how to take out the drill bit. The drill has from the top the drill bit, then I guess its called a head and then a base on which the head is mounted and then the plastic body with all the buttons etc. What do I have to do to take out the drill bit? What should be rotated in what direction? 
Heres a picture of the drill machine
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gzxuGu7rBIw

I dont want to screw up my drill or tighten the already jammed drill bit.

Comment: It has what's called a key chuck. Google that for instructions.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/892584/Black-And-Decker-Hammer-Drill.html) the manual for your drill?

Comment: I agree with user6591, Sometimes if you have strong hands you can reverse the drill and holding the outer sleeve tap the trigger and it will open up. +

Comment: [How do I remove a drill bit that is stuck due to an overtightened {keyless} chuck?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/how-do-i-remove-a-drill-bit-that-is-stuck-due-to-an-overtightened-chuck) Keyless or not, most of those suggestions apply.

Comment: The chuck key comment helped me. I just needed to know the direction and I found out that to open the drill bit, one needs to rotate the chuck key counterclockwise or the second method is to rotate the sleeve clockwise holding the head firm. I made multiple scratches on my drill machine using the wrench and everything, not knowing the direction .. But no worries - learning by doing.

Answer (score 2):

You may use your hands, a chuck key, or other means to loosen the chuck. See [page two of the manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/918337/Black-And-Decker-Hd400.html?page=2#manual). [Page 12](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/918337/Black-And-Decker-Hd400.html?page=12#manual) also mentions using the chuck key.